# How to segment a group of symmetric points

Tags: geometry

I have a closed shape represented by N points in a 2D space, and I know for sure that the points have some sort of symmetry. Given the N points, how can we segment them into two symmetric sets?

- Number of points is always even
- Points are always connected to form a closed shape

** [EDIT]

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TV7zs.jpg)

Comment: It might be my eyes, but can you clarify what kind of symmetry your example points have?

Comment: Maybe the previous example wasn't clear, but please see the updated one. Just picture a simple letter C.

Comment: So, essentially, what you have to do is to find the symmetry. Once you have the symmetry, segmenting symmetric becomes easy. By the way: is it allowed to choose one of the two sets to be empty? This would simplify the problem a bit...

Comment: I'm sorry If my examples are terrible. Just picture a perfectly symmetric shape. I just need guidance on how to achieve such a thing.

Comment: Yes it's alright to choose one of them to be empty. We can simply reflect it.

Comment: What I just found with 1 min using Google: https://langbein.org/wp-content/uploads/2008/12/li2008.pdf . Maybe a bit overdosed, but it might provide the right search keywords and ideas

Answer (score 0):

The author confirmed my question in the comments that it is allowed to choose one of the two sets to be empty. Trivially, the empty set is symmetric. By assumption, its complement (the whole set) is symmetric, too.

Thus, the simplest answer to the question is: segment the points such that one of the two sets is empty!